# Is the "Show Contact Deceased" extension compatible with 4.6?

Tags: extension, 4.6.0

Extension [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions/show-contact-deceased) shows as compatible through 4.5.  Is this compatible with 4.6?

What is the best way to determine whether something is likely not compatible with a contemporary Civi version rather than just not updated to reflect as much?

Comment: StackExchange works best if questions only have a single question. Could you post your second question as a separate question?

Comment: Thank you-- done so here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4587/how-can-i-determine-if-an-extension-is-compatible-with-a-new-civi-version

Comment: Is it possible to shift Jon G's answer below to this question, as it is very helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core team liked the extension so much that it was incorporated into core for 4.6. So we won't be releasing a 4.6 version. Thanks for your question - we will update the documentation on civicrm.org to reflect that it has gone into core for 4.6.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!