# Is there an automated way to check if a list of extensions is compatible with a version of Civi?

Tags: extension

I'm going to go through a list of installed extensions manually at civicrm.org/extensions and check, one by one, if each is compatible with CiviCRM 4.7.x , per the Q and A [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4587/how-can-i-determine-if-an-extension-is-compatible-with-a-new-civi-version) .

However, is there any way to *automate* that tedious process, from within the Civi UI and/or on the civicrm.org website? Extensions listed [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions) all show CiviCRM Compatibility version info.

Can a filter be added to the webpage to search by CiviCRM version compatibility, for say, just CiviCRM 4.7? A compact view created with the Extension names and a checkbox to select a subset of results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the [CMS independent](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm) tab within the extensions direcotry  page, there's a field to filter by "CiviCRM Compatibility". Here are the [extensions compatible with CiviCRM 4.7](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm?title=&cat=All&field_extension_release_civicrm_tid=216&sort_by=title&sort_order=DESC)

Comment: Hey thanks Sean that gets a ways there. It doesn't seem to actually sort by Title Ascending which is a bummer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a shell on the server (e.g. SSH), you can `cd` to the extensions directory and paste this command:

```
grep --recursive -l --include info.xml '<ver>4.7</ver>' *
```

This will search all the folders for files named 'info.xml' and then search the text of info.xml for the presence of the string that indicates 4.7 compatibility, returning a list of extensions.

This will NOT tell you which extensions have upgraded versions that are compatible with 4.7 - but it will cover all your extensions, including "unlisted" ones.

Of course, a great many extensions that aren't listed as 4.7 compatible still work in 4.7.

Comment: Jon thanks so much, I'll do the above. Since this info is in or should be in info.xml , seems like that gives enough info to somewhat automate CiviCRM compatibility check? And since extension developers will want their extension to show in that, incentive to update the info.xml info in their extension?  Thanks again.

Comment: and would grep --recursive -l --include info.xml '<ver>4.*</ver>' * show whatever 4.x info is in info.xml ?

Comment: @JoeMcLaughlin It would - but only by accident :)  I won't try to explain the "correct" regex.  Note that in this case, you should drop the "-l" argument, because you don't just want file names - you want a line returned for each line in info.xml, showing the version number.